How to properly integrate API calls in Next.js using useEffect and axios?
I'm developing a Next.js application where I need to fetch data from an API and handle it in both the frontend with useEffect and in API routes. Initially, I used a standard Node.js setup which worked, but when adapting it to the more standard Next.js structure, I'm encountering issues.
Here is the working Node.js version of my code:
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchModel = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/model/${id}`)
      const data: IArticlePublication = await response.json()
      setModel(data)
      console.log(data)
    }

    try {
      fetchModel()
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }, [])

import axios from 'axios'
import { IArticlePublication } from '@/interface/IBackend'

export const GET = async (req: any, { params }: any): Promise<Response> => {
  try {
    console.log(req)
    const { data } = await axios.get<IArticlePublication>(
      `http://localhost:3001/publications/model/${params.id}`
    )
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(data), { status: 200 })
  } catch (error: any) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: error.message }), {
      status: 500
    })
  }
}

And the "suggest" code is this, and doesnt works
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchModel = async () => {

      fetch(`/api/model/${id}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
    }

    try {
      fetchModel()
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }, [])

import axios from 'axios'
import { IArticlePublication } from '@/interface/IBackend'
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

export const GET = async (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.query
    const { data } = await axios.get<IArticlePublication>(
      `http://localhost:3001/publications/model/${id}`
    )
    res.status(200).json(data)
  } catch (error: any) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
  }
}


any error message ? you can log it out in the console
